# but before we do so and commas

Tags: commas

I have a sentence that is structured like:

> We need to perform a database cleanup, but before we do so, we were wondering if we could...

Is this the correct use of commas? Or would the proper use be one of the following:

> 1. We need to perform a database cleanup, but before we do so we were wondering if we could...

> 2. We need to perform a database cleanup but before we do so, we were wondering if we could...

Comment: Actually, I think there should be one more comma: "We need to perform a database cleanup, but, before we do so, we were wondering if we could..."

Comment: It depends on the style guide you use. The technically correct use of commas on either side of *but* is jarring (*We need to perform a database cleanup, but, before we do so, we were wondering if we could...*). Some guides suggest you omit the first comma (*We need to perform a database cleanup but, before we do so, we were wondering if we could...*). Others suggest you omit the second (*We need to perform a database cleanup, but before we do so, we were wondering if we could...*).

Comment: Ty both :)
I ended up sending the email as posted in original question with just the two commas. I decided I was probably the only person who was going to scrutinize it that much. xD